# Oracle SOA and MSA

Tags: soa, esb, microservices

Is it advicible to build the MSA based services on Oracle SOA or any other ESB suite for that matter? Is there any advantage or disadvantage?

If I am using Java, Spring and JPA over a message queue - say - RabbitMQ, I can achieve it in a more controlled environment with less recurring expenses. Of course will end up mixing tools like Drools or JBPM or similar to achieve things that may be OOTB (Out of the box) in the SOA Or ESB Suite. But scaling a specific service without paying licence fee for an additional environment should certainly be a good catch right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microservices architecture pattern applies to development of backend systems/services, whereas ESB (e.g. Oracle SOA Suite) is intended as an intermediary layer between consumers and backend services. Backend services contain rich application logic, whereas ESB services provide only intermediary functions like routing, transformation, orchestration etc.

ESB is not intended for rich application logic, though it's possible to do that.

Using ESB (e.g. Oracle SOA Suite) to host microservices is achievable, but you will get a big overhead comparing to limited functions and scalability. If you are looking for centralized API management (tracing, security etc.), you can put an API gateway into your architecture instead of full scale ESB.